# Python и Kivy - ошибка Invalid syntax,а я не вижу где ошибка

Tags: python, kivy

Сам код(я полный нуб,это первая прога,да)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

Config.set("graphics", "resizable", "0") 
Config.set("graphics", "width", "300")

Config.set("graphics", "height", "300")
class meladzeApp(App):
def playSound(self, som, instance):
    song = SoundLoader.load("Sound.mp3")
    song.play()
    self.playing.append(song)
class kivy.uix.button.Button(**kwargs)
btn1 = Button(text='KPACUBO')
background_color = [255, 0, 0, ,1]
btn1.bind(on_press=song.play)



def build(self):
    meladzeApp().run()
```

Ошибка Invalid Syntax на строке `class kivy.uix.button.Button(**kwargs)`

Comment: Не очень понимаю значение этой строчки, но Если вы создаёте класс, то надо ":" в конце, а если вы его бвызываете, то не надо писать слово "класс", и остальные модули где хранится сам класс

Comment: Короче,я пытаюсь создать кнопку которая проигрывает звук
Я загрузил звук,но до сих пор не могу понять как проиграть его,вот попытался класс создать и сделать таким образом кнопку

Comment: Так класс кнопки уже есть, вы его импортировади в 5 строчке кода, осталось только сделать экземпляр этого класса, кратко: строчку с ошибкой удалите